# how to add data from sql to c# with the same value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

Hi i want to add Restaurant names of any city and any district that i have in my database
and i have 5 Restaurant for each district  in each city
how can i add each one of them to my buttentexts
please look at the code and pictures

for example there is 5 Restaurantname with sehirid=25  and ilceid = 1

...
SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("Data Source = ALI\MSSQLSERVER01; Initial Catalog = YemekSepeti; Integrated Security = True");

```
    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        baglanti.Open();
        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_resturan where sehirid=25 and ilceid = @p1 ", baglanti);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Form2.svft2 + 1);
        komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader dr = komut.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {

            button1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
            button2.Text = dr[1].ToString();
            button3.Text = dr[1].ToString();
            button4.Text = dr[1].ToString();
            button5.Text = dr[1].ToString();


        }
        baglanti.Close();
    }
```

...

my code is working but i dont know what shoud i write in

```
            button2.Text = dr[?].ToString();
            button3.Text = dr[?].ToString();
            button4.Text = dr[?].ToString();
            button5.Text = dr[?].ToString();
```

Comment: instead of "select * " specify the Columns in the sql Text  then [?] becomes the index of the column you require.

Comment: http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: Please add the image you want to display. I don't know what you want to do. Could you show us a complete example?

Comment: Could you show your database table design? What is the type of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing logic that maps the correct row to the correct button. You are using a `SqlDataReader`, which is forward only, so everytime you call `dr.Read()` you only have access to the current row. This is a simple example that would do mapping but it is dependent on the way your DB returns the data.

```
int i = 1;
while (dr.Read())
{
    if (i == 1) 
      button1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
    if (i == 2)
      button2.Text = dr[1].ToString();
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reproduce your problem.Database creates tbl_resturan table and adds data.

[image]

Add 6 buttons to the form to display the data of the database query.

UI Page:

[image]

Code logic: enter data in the text box and click the confirm button. Query database to display data.

```
   private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
         Dao dao = new Dao();
      
         string sql = $"select *  from tbl_resturan where sehirid=25  and ilceid ='{textBox1.Text}' ";
         SqlDataReader dr = dao.read(sql);


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);  // load data table dataReader .
        var list = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(c => c.Field<string>("restname")).ToList();

        button1.Text = list[0].ToString();
        button2.Text = list[1].ToString();
        button3.Text = list[2].ToString();
        button4.Text = list[3].ToString();
        button5.Text = list[4].ToString();


    }
```

Encapsulates database operation code:

```
internal class Dao
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    public SqlConnection connection()
    {
        // write database connection string
        string connStr = "Data source=localhost;Initial Catalog=student;User ID=sa;Password=123456";
        conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();
        return conn;
    }

    public SqlCommand command(string sql)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection());
        return cmd;
    }

    public int Execute(string sql)
    {
        return command(sql).ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public SqlDataReader read(string sql)
    {
        return command(sql).ExecuteReader();
    }
    public void DaoClose()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

}
```

Project run:

[image]